# How to move separate items with the same tag in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried to create a program where the user adds certain logic gates and they can move separately.
I have tried to add a count and concatenate the tag but it will not work.
My program below is what I have so far, I need some help on how to move gates separately even if the same gate is added to the canvas.

```
from tkinter import *

canvas=Canvas(width=600,height=600)
canvas.grid()

def andGATE():
    canvas.create_line(150,50,150,150,width=5,tag="andgate")
    canvas.create_arc(150,50,200,150,start=90,extent=-180,width=5,fill="black",tag="andgate")



    canvas.create_line(150,75,120,75,width=5,tag="andgate")
    canvas.create_line(150,120,120,120,width=5,tag="andgate")
    canvas.create_line(200,100,250,100,width=5,tag="andgate")
    canvas.create_rectangle(150,50,180,150,width=5,fill="black",tag="andgate")
    canvas.tag_bind("andgate","<B1-Motion>",moveANDGate)

def gateSelected():
    sf=var.get()
    if sf=='AND':
        andGATE()

def moveANDGate(event):
    x=event.x
    y=event.y
    coords=canvas.coords("andgate")
    movex=x-coords[0]
    movey=y-coords[1]
    canvas.move("andgate",movex,movey)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
var = StringVar(root)
var.set('AND')
choices = ['AND']
option = OptionMenu(root, var, *choices)
option.pack(side="left",padx=10,pady=10)
button = Button(root, text="Add Gate", command=gateSelected)
button.pack(side="left",padx=10,pady=10)
clearButton = Button(root,text="Clear",command=lambda:clearScreen())
clearButton.pack(side="left",padx=30,pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You say *"I have tried to add a count and concatenate the tag but it will not work"*. For me, this actually seems like the right way to go. Could you share your efforts in trying this and where you get stuck?

Comment: This code doesn't work at all. When I click on "Add Gate", an error is thrown. Plus, you end up creating two root windows rather than once, since you're creating the canvas before explicitly creating a root window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a unique tag for each collection of canvas items that make up a single gate. You can then move all of the items together by using that unique tag.

To keep the implementation simple, I'll illustrate by using a global variable for the id of each new gate. Using a global variable isn't the best solution, but it's certainly the simplest.

Also to make things simple for this answer, we'll add a binding for each tag, which passes the tag to the move function. It's also possible to have a single binding for the canvas which will first determine which gate was clicked on. For the purpose of this answer we'll keep it simple and create a unique binding for each gate.

First, we need to modify `moveANDgate` to accept the unique tag, so that it knows which one needs to be moved:

```
def moveANDGate(event, tag):
    x=event.x
    y=event.y
    coords=canvas.coords(tag)
    movex=x-coords[0]
    movey=y-coords[1]
    canvas.move(tag, movex, movey)
```

Next, we need to create a global variable that we can use to generate a unique tag. we can then use that variable inside of `andGATE` to create the tag and add it to all of the items in the canvas. We then need to bind a function to the `<B1-Motion>` event for our new tag.:

```
gate_id = 0
def andGATE():
    global gate_id
    gate_id += 1
    gate_tag = "andgate-%s" % gate_id
    tags = ("andgate", gate_tag)

    canvas.create_line(150, 50, 150, 150, width=5, tags=tags)
    canvas.create_arc(150, 50, 200, 150, start=90, extent=-180, width=5, fill="black", tags=tags)

    canvas.create_line(150, 75, 120, 75, width=5, tags=tags)
    canvas.create_line(150, 120, 120, 120, width=5, tags=tags)
    canvas.create_line(200, 100, 250, 100, width=5, tags=tags)
    canvas.create_rectangle(150, 50, 180, 150, width=5, fill="black", tags=tags)

    canvas.tag_bind(gate_tag, "<B1-Motion>", lambda event, tag=gate_tag: moveANDGate(event, tag))
```

In this example I'm giving each item two tags: one that is the static string "andgate", and one that has the id. This makes it possible to do something to all of the andgate objects at once, or to do something for a specific andgate. Think of `"andgate"` as a class name, and `"andgate-<number>"` as an instance name. That's not exactly what they are, but logically that is how they are used.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. :)

Comment: @c.s.b: yes, that should be possible.